# (sed) Remove comma between any two numbers inside double quote (but keep the number)

Tags: csv, sed

I need to sanitize a CSV that lists some numbers. For 4 and more digits, it gives the number in double quotes with comma. I need to remove this type of comma.

So far I got this:

`sed 's/"[0-9]*\,[0-9]*"/"idk"/g'`

Which successfully identifies the comma I am looking for apart from the other commas.

```
example,134,"idk",0.91%,8.0
example,96,"idk",2.62%,6.9
example,89,367,3.68%,5.8
```

How do I tell sed I only need to remove the comma out of the match query though?

**Edit**: Sorry, expected output is just to remove the comma.

in: `example,89,"1,456",3.68%,5.8`

out: `example,89,"1456",3.68%,5.8`

Comment: Are you looking for `sed 's/\("[0-9]*\),\([0-9]*"\)/\1\2/g'`? (No need to backslash the comma, it has no special meaning in regex.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tell sed to "remember" the other parts and use them in replacement string. Ie. use a backreference.

```
sed 's/\("[0-9]*\),\([0-9]*"\)/\1\2/g'
```